# XMing - "XIO: fatal IO error 11

Tags: xming

I am running Xming 6.9.0.31 on my local Windows 7 workstation.  I am accessing a Ubuntu server to view large data sets graphically in my Xming session.  When I request a smaller data set I have no problem but when I access a very large data set I receive the following error:

```
IO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server "localhost:13.0"
      after 629 requests (164 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
```

tks,
steve

Comment: How are you accessing the data sets? Is it one application instance or many? Which application is it?

Comment: Hi Bananguin, I use SecureCRT to access the cloud-based data.  Perhaps its a network issue? Was thinking it was a local computer resource/memory issue...steve

Comment: Did your SSH session seem unaffected?

Comment: If you right click the xming icon in the taskbar by the clock "view log" should be one of the options. There may be something in that (if that's not where the above error came from, I mean).

Comment: Hello Joel, the SSH session remains open and once the Xming plot fails the session functions as expected...I deleted the log file then reran the command that causes the issue and nothing additional is written to the log file, no clues there.